# Completion when pasting Bash command beginning with tabs

Tags: command-line, bash, autocomplete, tab-completion, readline

I'm writing a `Dockerfile` which I'm formatting using tabs (which I usually use everywhere).

But I've copied a multi-line command where the second line begins with two tab characters, i.e.:

```
apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install collectd \ # begin two tabs
```

The first line executes correctly but the second line tries to "autocomplete", show all possible commands, and then:

```
> stall collectd
# [ apt-get updating ]
bash: stall: command not found
```

I understand the "autocompleting" behaviour, but `stall collectd`? Why does Bash eat the `apt-get -y in` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chaos' answer](https://superuser.com/a/926040/164774) clearly explains how to disable this behaviour but I interpreted this question as being motivated by curiousity about what happened to the first part of the `apt-get` command:

If you were to type two tabs, Bash would ask if you want to,

> Display all 5177 possibilities? (y or n)?

*Note that the number of possibilities depends on your own environment.*

If you were to reply with any of the characters in the string `apt-get -`, Bash would ignore them since it only wants a yes or a no. When it gets the `y`, it displays all the possibilities.

In modern versions of Bash, this list is displayed in a pager which has a `More?` prompt at the bottom. The pager uses the space character to scroll down a page, ignores the following `i` but the next character, `n` is interpreted as a “No” to exit the pager.

Finally, the remaining characters, `stall collectd` are interpreted by the shell as a command.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the completion behavior of `bash` when pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key:

```
bind 'set disable-completion on'
```

Now, the <kbd>tab</kbd> key just indents the line as inside an editor. This is just temporary. At the next shell session it's not set. If you want ot make it permantent add that to your `~/.inputrc`.

To re-enable the <kbd>tab</kbd> key use:

```
bind 'set disable-completion off'
```

Comment: Can you explain why we can't just enter `set disable-completion off` in the shell/why I have to pass it as a string to the `bind` command?